# BibLateX error when I insert \begin{figure}

Tags: biblatex, floats, linguistics

I am working on a paper and I am using the BibLateX package for my bibliography. When I try to insert a figure using `\begin{figure}` the compilation fails and it gives me an error of the type >Package biblatex Error: Option 'related' already defined. The error is repeated multiple times with different words instead of "related" (e.g. url, doi, isbn, etc.) I am not sure how LaTeX works but it seems like bibLaTeX is trying to use already defined variables? Anyway, here's a sample of my code:

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
%

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}


\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[citestyle=chicago-authordate]{biblatex} %Imports biblatex package
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} %Import the bibliography file

\usepackage{ccg-latex}
%\usepackage{mathptmx} % this font is for demo. CM fonts look ugly.

\usepackage{gb4e}
%\usepackage{lscape}
%\usepackage[linguistics]{forest} %to draw syntax trees 
%\usepackage{ulem}
%\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}
%
\title{German Verb Particles Constructions in CCG}%\thanks{}}

\author{Name}

\authorrunning{Name}

\institute{University Name}

\email{example@example.edu}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

Abstract Text

\keywords{word1 \and word2 \and word3}

\end{Abstract}


\section{Introduction}

Text of document with an example using gb4e for Linguistics style. 

\begin{exe}
    \ex \label{} \textbf{Continuous Order}
    \begin{xlist}
        \ex[]{The police \textbf{tracked down} the thief.} 
        \ex[]{Anna \textbf{looked up} the book.}
    \end{xlist}
    
    \ex \textbf{Discontinuous Order}
    \begin{xlist}
        \ex[]{The police \textbf{tracked down} the thief.}
        \ex[]{Anna \textbf{looked up} the book.}
    \end{xlist}
\end{exe}


Some more text with a citation (\cite{source-1})

.
.
.

Here I add a figure to my document:

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{images/myimage.png
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I am very new at LaTeX so I am not sure what the error might be or how to fix it. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Currently, there is no `\begin{figure}` in your code, yet it results in the above described error.

Comment: An even more minimal example that still produces the error is `\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

\usepackage[citestyle=chicago-authordate]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}` leading to the conclusion that the `llncs` class is simply incompatible with `biblatex`.

Comment: oops! sorry i added the figure now!

and ok, so that'd mean i'd have to use a different citing package? the original template had a different one but i am not used to working with it so i used biblatex instead.

Comment: I am afraid, the class is incompatible with `biblatex`. Stick with the different package, that the original template used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting can be reproduced in the following example using a standard class

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[citestyle=chicago-authordate]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The package call `\usepackage[citestyle=chicago-authordate]{biblatex}` from the MWE is equivalent to

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=numeric, citestyle=chicago-authordate]{biblatex}
```

The problem here is that the citation styles of the `biblatex-chicago` package cannot be combined freely with other bibliography styles. In particular the citation styles of the `biblatex-chicago` bundle appear to define some options that are defined by the standard `biblatex` styles. This produces the errors we see here.

The code works if you use the same citation and bibliography style, i.e.

```
\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate]{biblatex}
```

Independent of this issue, I believe this is the code most people want. It is rarely necessary or useful to separately set `bibstyle` and `citestyle` independently. Using `style` to set `bibstyle` and `citestyle` at the same time almost always gives better results.

**But** the `biblatex-chicago` styles are special. They should *not* be loaded via `\usepackage{biblatex}`, they should be loaded via the `biblatex-chicago` wrapper package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This will also work with `llncs`

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

Before you go through with `biblatex` or `biblatex-chicago` in `llncs` note that its documentation `llncsdoc` says

> We encourage you to use BibTeX for typesetting your references. For formatting the bibliography according to Springer’s standard (for mathematics, physical sciences, and computer science), please use the bibliography style file `splncs04.bst` that comes with the LLNCS document class. You simply need to add `\bibliographystyle{splncs04}` to your document. DOIs should be provided in the `doi` field of your `.bib` database.

This means you probably should not use `biblatex` (or `biblatex-chicago`) with `llncs`. Indeed Springer may not be able or willing to accept submissions using `biblatex`. I suggest you double-check with the editor/your contact at Springer whether they can accept `biblatex` submissions.

Note that the preference for standard BibTeX methods may well mean that `llncs.cls` is not tested with `biblatex`. It contains quite some code for the standard LaTeX/BibTEX way of citing, but no code for `biblatex`.

If you are not planning to submit to Springer's LLNCS I suggest you look for a document class different from `llncs`. A standard class like `article` will probably mean less hassle in the future.